# Check the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{10n+17}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I`m trying to check if this series convergent
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{10n+17}$$
I decided to do it with Cauchy condensation test:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt[n]{ \frac{n}{10n+17}} = 1$$the meaning is that we dont have enough information, so I need to do it with another test.

what your are suggest?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Use the simplest and most obvious test: what is

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{10n+17}\;?$$

Comment: it will give me $\frac{1}{10}$ if its not $0$ its Diverging?

Comment: @Ofir: That’s right: if $\sum a_n$ converges, the sequence of terms must converge to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that,

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{10n+17}=1/10.
 $$

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple series. you do not need any test for this. Just observe that the $n^{th}$ term does not go to zero.

$$\lim\frac{n}{10n+17} = 0.1$$

Answer (score 1):

The terms of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{10n+17}$ are $\frac{n}{10n+17}$ for positive integers $n$. If $n$ is absurdly large, then these terms are absurdly close to $\frac{1}{10}$. Surely, adding $\frac{1}{10}$ repeatedly with itself infinitely many times cannot result in a finite number. Also, for the reason that the terms are absurdly close to $\frac{1}{10}$ if $n$ is absurdly large, so must the ratios and $n$th root be absurdly close to $1$ if $n$ is absurdly large. So, neither the ratio nor the root test helps us.

There's the informal argument. However, there's a formal test that you learn right at the beginning of your studies of this stuff that makes this precise. It's a convergence test; what's its name?

I hope this helps!